# How to check comma separated value is already exists in SQL column?

Tags: sql

I have column in table as Deleted_Questions and its values are like
e.g. -  1,2,4,7,10

While inserting a new value in this column how we can check string is already exists ,
In my case I am going to insert string value like '4,' which is already exists in column.

Comment: which RDBMS are you using? MySQL,SQL Server,postgresql,..... . tag it correctly

Comment: The correct solution is to normalize your data model, not fight this ugly and bad design.

Comment: maybe useful? [The FIND_IN_SET function of Structured Query Language shows the position of the searched string in the multiple strings.](https://www.javatpoint.com/find_in_set-function-in-sql)